# Getting started with accessibility

Tags: iphone, ipad, accessibility

What are the typical mistakes an iPhone developer unaware of accessibility makes that renders their app unusable by customers with common impairments?

What are the first and easiest steps to take when making an iPhone app accessible to the vision impaired (etc.)?

How do I make sure Voice Over says or does something appropriate for all my programmatically created UIButtons, UISliders, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following link from Apple on accessibility on iOS.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html
I strongly suggest using voiceover to test your application after you've used the developer tools to check it's accessibility. I'm a blind iPod touch user and find that VoiceOver has a very low entry barrior, unlike windows screen reading software that requires you to memorize a bunch of keystrokes and realize that your application may be presented in an entirely different way to the user then you expect.

Comment: So what's the first or biggest accessibility problem you find that most apps need fixing in your experience?  (I prefer to ruthlessly prioritize within my limited development budget.)

Comment: I don't use a lot of apps but the biggest issue I've founed is poorly labeled controls. Your button may have a nice picture so the user can see what it does but if it has a name like name_only_programmer_understands this won't do a lot of good.